# VB.NET : Getting all the values in DataGridView then storing it to an Access Database

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, ms-access-2010, fetch

I used the `DataGridView` instead of using a lot of textbox and combobox, that way I won't have to input data one by one and I could just do it in one go.
My database in access looks exactly the same as my datagrid. Same column number, same column names. 
How do I transfer all the data I've put on the datagrid into my database when I click the Add button.

[image: sample screeny]

Comment: This question can easily be solved by googling for tutorials for DataGridView. The question is basically: write me a tutorial from start to finish on how to store input via a datagridview in MS Access.

Comment: Voted to close your question as too broad. This is something you can use google for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add a BIND to your database. This way, all changes and inputs will be realtime put into database.

See:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can also see this: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/402532/populate-datagridview-table-from-access-table

Comment: so if i put a bind to my database, would it display the data from the database?
what I mean on my question is that I'm only using the datagrid like an input field, and that I only want to put the inputted data to the database not display what's on the database.

Comment: If you bind the datagridview using Table and Dataset, you may ALWAYS display an empty datagridview (no data at all) and provide your own ADD button - the difference from do this using BINDING is just about the less efforts to add data. You do not need to manually add field-by-field. But, if preferable, you may also do it field-by-field using, for sample, this video as tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtE3kkQR7_w

Comment: got it, thanks a lot. im sorry btw, i really am new at vb and I've been searching at google since this morning. This is the first post that has helped me, didn't know about binding tho, this really helped. thanks again

Comment: My pleasure... :)  But, if it help it some way, please vote (if you guess I deserve your vote).  Thank you and good luck.